# Dynamic getting of data in php

Tags: php, html

I have a search form which has four filter textboxes. What I want to do is whenever the user submits the form, only those textboxes that has values will be submitted and searched for. I know how to do it in if else statement, but it's too long to write it in code. Is there any other shorter methods?

Comment: What else do you expect, only four filters won't be too complicated. And please make your question clear, from what datasource are you searching.

Comment: `$search = array_filter(array_intersect_key($_POST.array_flip('these','are'.'the','search','field','names')));` or something? For anything more I'd have to see the actual code you want to use.

Comment: I want to search from database, and each of the textboxes have different categories. If the user only type something on the first textbox and nothing to the others, it should only search from the category inputted in the first textbox. . . something like that

Comment: should use switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code. You can implement search condition in the foreach loop.

```
// HTML field names
$fields = array_flip(array("search1", "search2", "search3", "search4"));

$data = array_filter(array_intersect_key($_POST, $fields));

foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    // Here you can implement the sql search condtion
    echo "$key => $val" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Process.php

```
<?php


if (($_POST['First'])== TRUE);
 $Fv = $_POST['First'];
if(($_POST['Second'])== TRUE);
$Sv = $_POST['Second'];
if(($_POST['Third'])!= TRUE);
$Tv = $_POST['Third'];
if(($_POST['Fourth'])!= TRUE);
$Fov = $_POST['Fourth'];

echo $Fv;
echo"</br>";
echo $Sv;
echo"</br>";
echo $Tv;
echo"</br>";
echo $Fov;

?>
```

search.php

```
<?php

echo '<html>
<body>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
First: <input type="text" name="First"><br>
Second: <input type="text" name="Second"><br>
Third: <input type="text" name="Third"><br>
Fourth: <input type="text" name="Fourth"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html> ';
?>
```

Only the values entered with be echoed.

Comment: You can put checks, to see from which variable the data is being echoed, you can use that to search for stuff inside the db.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
search.php

```
 $sql = " select * from table name where 1=1 "

   if (($_POST['First'])!='');
    $sql .= ' AND first = "'.$_POST['First'].'"';
   if(($_POST['Second'])!='');
    $sql .= ' AND Second = "'.$_POST['Second'].'"';
   if(($_POST['Third'])!='');
    $sql .= ' AND Third = "'.$_POST['Third'].'"';
   if(($_POST['Fourth'])!='');
    $sql .= ' AND Fourth = "'.$_POST['Fourth'].'"';
```

Or try this

```
$arr = $_POST;
     $sql = " select * from table name where 1=1 "
     foreach($arr as $key =>$ar){
       if($ar!='')  $sql .= ' AND '.$key.' = "'.$ar.'"';
     }
```

The input name and db field name must be same...

Comment: just only one if statement